# Home shortcut on Apple bluetooth keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using an Apple Bluetooth keyboard with my Android 7.0 tablet. The software keyboard I'm using is Swiftkey. I use Swiftkey because it's one of only two keyboards capable of typing the Maltese language (the other being Multiling keyboard). There's no Maltese layout in Android.

Everything works fine, but I cannot find a shortcut to go to the Home screen. I've searched on the web and most sites suggested that the Esc key should do that, but in my case it functions as a Back button.

I tried Fn + Esc, Cmd + Esc, Alt + Esc, Ctrl + Esc to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out which shortcut key corresponds to Home. It is cmd + return. It seems that the cmd key corresponds to the search key in the list of shortcuts available in the Physical keyboard settings.
[image: Android Nougat keyboard shortcuts helper]

Comment: What is the ' at sign'  shortcut that separates email recipient and domain?

Comment: It is alt (right) + 0.